# jQuery Mobile no styling after using Ajax .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using an Ajax call to get a list of checkboxes to appear in a panel after the user presses login. The data loads in fine but there is no JQM styling on it, its only the default browser styling. The id of the checklist is filterlist, and the div where I want to put it is called test1.

javascript:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#loginbutton', function() {
        $( "#test1" ).load( "test.html #filterlist" );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(document).on('click', '#loginbutton', function() {
    $( "#test1" ).load( "test.html #filterlist" );
    $( "#test1" ).trigger ('create');
});
```

this will apply the jquery mobile styling to the newly created elements, if it is loading a page you might try 'pagecreate' instead

Comment: @chrispytoes you have to make sure it is triggered after the load finishes.. sorry for the poor example put it on the #test1.onload callback